# How does Volume work with integration?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, volume, applications

Using a cross section suppose, as described here: [Area formula Paul Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/Area_Volume_Formulas.aspx)

[image: Ruby Fapshire]

Suppose this is: $y = f(x)$.

He says the volume is:

$$\int_{a}^{b} A(x) dx$$

But how does area over that interval give the volume? I mean,

You are not getting the area of a cross section **(the YELLOW part)** are you? You are just taking the area of The 2D region, which isnt the cross section?

[image: ruby gagshire]

Then how does summing that area give the volume when its not the cross section? The actual cross section is the yellow part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A(x)$ represents the area of the cross section. It is a circle of radius $f(x)$. Thus $A(x)=\pi\,f(x)^2$.

To see that the integral gives the volume imagine the solid of revolution is a salami and you cut it in thin slices of width $dx$. The volume of each slice is $A(x)\,dx$, and when you sum them all you get the volume of the salami.

Comment: $A(x) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$. What they are saying is: 

$$V = \int_{a}^{b} A(x) dx$$. $f(x)$ is defined in $2D$, how is the radius of the circle $= f(x)$?

Comment: Just look at the picture. You are rotating the graph of $y=f(x)$. Imagine a vertical line from $(x,0)$ to $(x,f(x))$. As it rotates, it generates a circle, whose area is $A(x)$. $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ is the area of the green region in the picture, nothing to do with $A(x)$.

Comment: but how is the radius $f(x)$?

Comment: Look at the picture of the graph of $f$. The black line situated at $x=b$ is the radius of he circle of area $A(b)$. What is the length of the line?

Comment: $f(x)$, BUT, when the solid is in $3D$ then for example when the disk is towards the right side, in the $3D$ plane, how is the radius still $f(x)$?

Comment: I am unable to understand what is it that you cannot understand. Just look at the picture.

Comment: I know @Julian. The issue is you say $f(x)$ is the radius. That is correct, but the figure is in $3D$ isnt it? Then how is the radius ALWAYS $f(x)$? Meaning, take the semi circle in $2D$. On the complete right hand side, how is the radius to there still $f(x)$? Shouldnt it be a function of two variables? $f(x, y)$?

Comment: You mean that the semicircle rotates and generates a sphere?

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as 
\begin{align}
V 
&= 
\int\limits_V dV 
\quad 
\mbox{(adding up tiny Volume elements over the volume)} \\ 
&= 
\int\limits_a^b A(x) \, dx 
\quad 
\mbox{(adding up slices $dV = A(x)\,dx$ along the $x$-axis)}\\ 
&= 
\int\limits_a^b \int\limits_0^{f(x)} \int\limits_0^{2\pi} y\, dx \, dy \, d\varphi \\
\end{align}
Where
$$
A(x) 
= 
\int\limits_0^{f(x)} dA 
= 
\int\limits_0^{f(x)} 2\pi y dy = \pi f(x)^2
$$ 
results from a summation of circular strips $dA$
and the circular strips result from summing up the elements
$y\,dy\,d\varphi$ over the circle
$$
dA = \int\limits_0^{2\pi} y \, dy \, d\phi = 2\pi y\, dy
$$

Comment: If OP cannot make heads or tails of the picture I dont think multiple variables will help. Questions like the one posted are taught in single-variable calculus in the US.

Comment: You are probably right. But I hope to illustrate that a volume integration involves three 1D integrations.

Comment: @mvw, no its fine. I know multivcariable calculus, the only issue is I was RETURNING back to single variable.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x)$ going from left to right of the graph simply defines the shape. With the $\pi$ constant it makes it into a circle, that is to say you're rotating the shape around the $x$-axis by $360$ degrees. Therefore, $f(x) \;  \textbf{becomes}$ the radius at each point $x$. You're simply adding up the circles with the varying radius $f(x)$.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

During rotation or sweeping the green area you are summing up many slices of the thin yellow circle pancakes along *axis* , but there is no connection to the green *meridional* cross section you sketched.

However if you want to find the volume of straight prismatic piece of cheese of cross section shaped that way, just multiply the green area by the distance moved normal to the green area along $z$ to find the linearly swept volume.